# Selenium Setting Window Size in Chrome Fails with Version 56.0.2924.87

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, robotframework

I am using selenium to automate ui testing with google chrome.  As part of my testing, I resize windows several times during the suite.

I am using RobotFramework's Selenium2Library to get the job done with the following two keywords:

```
Set Window Size | 1080 | 800

Maximize Browser Window
```

Which are essentially just thin wrappers around the python selenium functions of the same name.  Some time in the last few days, all the tests that involve window resizing began failing, and I *think* the culprit is the newest version of chrome.

The error:

```
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot get automation
extension from unknown error: page could not be found:
chrome-extension://aapnijgdinlhnhlmodcfapnahmbfebeb/_generated_background_page.html
```

When I tried altering the screen size with:

```
driver.execute_script("window.resizeTo({},{})".format(width, height))
```

I get no response at all (no error or change to window size)

Does anyone have a workaround for this?  It is important that we keep the suite in chrome, and I need to resize during the test if at all possible.

Thanks,

Joe

Comment: Download chrome driver version 2.28, it will fix this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of chromedriver do you use? This problem happened to me before I upgraded to version 2.28 along with update of Chrome to v57 (previously I used 2.26 and the error with the very same message as yours appeared).

Comment: I've actually been trying to figure that out, my installation doesn't seem to have any version info.  I'll go ahead and re-install chromedriver with the latest version and post my results.  Thanks for the tip

Comment: That did the trick, thanks!  Interestingly the js execute_script still does not work, but I won't need it now that the regular selenium api does.